# Text file not reading c++ MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, file-io, ifstream

I have an issue with some code I have been working on. I am trying to read the contents of a text file (input.txt) into a variable fileContents. The loop in the code enters, but the program produces no output. Some of the variables are not used, I know about this. What is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  ifstream input("input.txt");
  ofstream output("output.txt"); //init output controller

  // new lines will be skipped unless we stop it from happening:
  //input.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

  // count the newlines with an algorithm specialized for counting:
  unsigned line_count = std::count(std::istream_iterator<char>(input),std::istream_iterator<char>(), '\n');

  string fileContents = ""; //init message, that will be filled by input.txt
  string str; //temp string

  while (input >> fileContents)
  {
    //cout << "loop entered";
    cout << fileContents << "\n";
  }

  //cout << "test" << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the moment nothing is being written to the output file. Removed an `output << fileContents;` while debugging?

Comment: `unsigned line_count = std::count(std::istream_iterator<char>(input),std::istream_iterator<char>(), '\n');` should read to the end of `input`, there is no rewinding of `input`, so I can't see how  the loop can be entered.

Comment: -user4581301 Yes the output file is just a stub, not being used. I want to get to the point where I can at least get the file into memory.

Comment: -user4581301 Commented out that line, still produces no output.

Comment: Test that input was `opened`. If not check that the program's working directory is where you expect it to be. Something like `char buf[1024]; cout << getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf));`

Comment: -user4581301 if (input.is_open()) does not execute :(

Comment: Good odds then that the directory you stored input in is not the same directory the program is being run from. Either use that little code snippet from my last comment or go hunting on your computer for where the program wrote the output.txt file and move input.txt to the same location.

Comment: -user4581301 That seemed to do the trick! Any idea how to change the location of where it is looking for the files? Should I specify the file path when creating the stream objects?

Comment: I like to use the full path so I can get predictability, but if you're handing this in as homework, your path probably won't match the marker's path (unless the assignment spec specifies a path). There are whole bunch of strategies and philosophies as to where you get that full path from if your program is going to be portable and requires a bunch of supporting files. That's a question unto itself.

Comment: -user4581301 For the record this isn't homework, jut getting practice in C++. I can figure out the path stuff on my own later. Thanks for your help!